# Why was Courant's "Methods of Mathematical Physics" suppressed, by the Germans, during WW2?

Tags: mathematics, physics, mathematical-physics

In the preface to [Methods of Mathematical Physics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471504475) Richard Courant, the author, wrote that the book was suppressed by the National Socialist rulers(Nazi) of Germany.

Hence, my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I think because [Richard Courant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Courant)

> left Germany in 1933, earlier than many Jewish escapees. He did not lose his position due to being Jewish, as his previous service as a front-line soldier exempted him; however, his public membership in the social-democratic left was reason enough (for the Nazis) for dismissal.

See the dates of the editions of [Methoden der mathematischen Physik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methoden_der_mathematischen_Physik).